# How to create nested JSON data type?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, nested

I want to creat the `JSON` file of the following data to create dropdown menues in using JavaScript code.

The user first chooses the item, this will limit the size options. Then, he/she will use the size, and based on the selection price will be determined.
After choosing all the required elements, the final price will be calculated.

```
item   size             price ($)
 A      less than 3      5
 A      greater than 3   4
 B      less than 10     6
 B      between 10 & 20  5
 B      greater than 20  4
```

Here is what I have written so far:

```
items = [
    {
        "item" : "A",
        "size_1"  : "less than 3",
        "size_2"  : "greater than 3",
        "price_1"     : "5"
        "price_2"     : "4"
    },
    {
        "item" : "B",
        "size_1"  : "less than 10",
        "size_2"  : "between 10 & 20",
        "size_3"  : "greater than 20",
        "price_1"     : "6"
        "price_2"     : "5"
        "price_3"     : "4"
    }
]
```

Is this how I should have done it? What is the best way to do so?

Comment: I think you want something more like `[{ "item": "A", "size": "less than 3", "price": 5 }, ...]` and so on.

Comment: @MikeC, if I want to create a dropdown menue of items, will it only show the `A` & `B` options once?

Comment: I guess that all depends on how you make a dropdown out of it.

Comment: I can think of about 3 different ways that data could be represented - use case is important

Comment: @MikeC, the other question is how to associate price and size?

Comment: In general, any time you find yourself creating variables or properties like `size_1`, `size_2`, etc. you should probably have an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you how you want to model your data. The way you have is fine, but there are benefits to having every item's data-model looking the same. I would probably do the following:

```
var items = [
  {"item": "A", "size": "less than 3", "price": 5},
  {"item": "A", "size": "greater than 3", "price": 4},
  {"item": "B", "size": "less than 10", "price": 6},
  {"item": "B", "size": "between 10 & 20", "price": 5},
  {"item": "B", "size": "greater than 20", "price": 4},
];
```

If you didn't need items to be a list with order, you could make it a map where `item` seems to be a key:

```
var items = {
  "A": [
    {"size": "less than 3", "price": 5},
    {"size": "greater than 3", "price": 4}
  ],
  "B": [
    {"size": "less than 10", "price": 6},
    {"size": "between 10 & 20", "price": 5},
    {"size": "greater than 20", "price": 4}
  ]
];
```

Etc. You could come up with tons of ways to represent your data. Only you know what makes the most sense for your implementation.